# Getting the `The application failed to initialize properly`/3221225794 error executing a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2008-r2

There is a *scheduled task* that is attached to a *custom event* in the `EventLog`, it executes the lines below:

**reconnect.cmd**

> c:\windows\system32\rasphone -f "phone_book.pbk" -d "vpn_connection"
>
> net stop my_windows_service
>
> net start my_windows_service

The task ususally runs normally without errors. But sometimes it returns error `The application failed to initialize properly (3221225794)`. The task is configured to run under `system` account so it is supposed to have all required permissions to run that batch script.

Why do I keep getting this error? What can cause it and how do I debug it?

**edit: start in option**

The task uses `"D:\"` as working directory/start in location. The reconnect.cmd script is located at `"D:\"`. Can this be the cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know why but running tasks under `SYSTEM` account was the cause. When we changed the account simply to `local admin` tasks ran flawlessly.

Comment: Let me guess - you also set the flag "interact with desktop".  It very well be that the 0xc0000142 error was because of a desktop heap issue.  When you run as a user, and interact with the desktop, it is able to support many more processes than running under the SYSTEM account (each one takes up a bit of the hard-defined desktop heap.  Yep, desktop heap DOES NOT GROW - IT IS FIXED.  We spent YEARS dealing with this issue in production with our Windows customers that were using our product.

Answer (score 1):

I posted this article earlier today on how to decode errors [Error 2147463168 when trying to bind to an AD User Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25146263/error-2147463168-when-trying-to-bind-to-an-ad-user-object/25148041#25148041)

```
//
// MessageId: STATUS_DLL_INIT_FAILED
//
// MessageText:
//
// {DLL Initialization Failed}
// Initialization of the dynamic link library %hs failed. The process is terminating abnormally.
//
#define STATUS_DLL_INIT_FAILED           ((NTSTATUS)0xC0000142L)
```

3221225794=0xC0000142 (use calculator)

This should identify which process (cmd or rasphone) and which dll.

You can also start in a debugger.

windbg or ntsd (ntsd is a console program and maybe installed). Both are also from Debugging Tools For Windows.

Download and install Debugging Tools for Windows

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/hh852363

Install the Windows SDK but just choose the debugging tools.

Create a folder called Symbols in C:\

Start `Windbg`. *File* menu - *Symbol File Path* and enter

```
srv*C:\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
```

then

```
windbg -o -g -G C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /k d:\batfile.bat
```

You can press F12 to stop it and kb will show the call stack (g continues the program). If there's errors it will also stop and show them.