# COM Interface - Connection to device fails

Tags: delphi, tcp, com, vb6, freepascal

I am using a COM interface to connect to an external device that is connected to the computer running the software via TCP/IP. I am posting this, because on one system this connection fails, mysteriously.

From the manufacturer, I have received an instrument.dll and an instrument.tlb. Unfortunately, details and code are subject to a confidentiality agreement, so I can only provide pseudocode.

I have two minimal examples, one on Free Pascal (the important one, because this is where I am developing):

```
uses
   Instrument_TLB; // Imported via the Lazarus "Import Type Library" function from the .tlb or the .dll

[...]

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  AInstrument := CoInstrument.Create;
  if AInstrument.Connected then ...
end;
```

and one on Visual Basic, provided by the manufacturer:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
   Set theInstrument = New Instrument
   If theInstrument.Connected Then ...
End Sub
```

This VB6 project has the instrument.dll as a reference.

The behaviour on different computers is as follows (supplemented with information from Sysinternals Process Explorer):

- System A (Windows XP, 32bit, used for compilation): Both the FP and the VB executable work as expected, a connection can be established. In Process Explorer, both executables have one thread with instrument.dll and the TCP/IP connection can be seen to be up.
- System B (Windows 7, 64bit): Both the FP and the VB executable work as expected, a connection can be established. Process Explorer was not used.
- System C (Windows 7, 64bit): The VB executable works as expected, a connection can be established. In Process Explorer the VB executable has one thread with instrument.dll and the TCP/IP connection can be seen to be up. The FP executable can NOT connect, there are **two** threads with instrument.dll and **no** TCP/IP connection seen in Process Explorer.

I know that based on the little information I am able to give, no one can come up with a "solution" - however, advice on how to investigate this problem further, what tools to use for debugging would be highly appreciated!

Thanks for your time.

Comment: VB uses COM automation. I suggest you use the same mechanism in Lazarus. (Does Lazarus allow you to import a type library?).

Comment: Is the DLL 32bit or 64bit? Is the FP app 32bit or 64bit? Did you ensure that `CoInitialize/Ex()` is being called before calling `CoInstrument.Create()`? When the app fails, is there an error message being reported?

Comment: @RemyLebeau both the FP application and the DLL are 32bit, CoInitialize is called. .Create is successful (no exception), but .Connected never returns true and all other method calls return error statuses.

Comment: @LeRookie: Did you sniff the network to make sure the DLL is actually trying to connect to the server at all? Unless the DLL exposes error information, such as via [`GetErrorInfo()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221032.aspx), you will most likely have to discuss this issue with the manufacturer so they can debug the DLL. There is no way for anyone here to troubleshoot this kind of problem for you.

Comment: @RemyLebeau GetErrorInfo() returns S_FALSE, so nothing available here. I will try a network sniffer later. I know that this problem can not be solved here, I just want to have tried everything I can befor escalating the issue. Your feedback is very helpful for doing so!

Comment: COM returns error info in the function return. In VB it might look like it returns the data but the data is an out parameter to the function and the error is the return.Anyway see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25153262/getting-the-the-application-failed-to-initialize-properly-3221225794-error-exe on how to debug. Type `x` to list the symbols and `bp symbolname` to set a breakpoint. `kb` lists stack and parameters.

Comment: @Noodles No, the VB6 program returns actual, valid data from the instrument! I will have a look at your other message though - thanks!

Comment: My point was to point out that VB mangles com. Error is the return code in real life. Therefore to get the error you'll need to get the return code of something like this (this is vb convert to pascal - use `x` to work it out). ie `x ued!*` in VB this is a COM EXE program called UEd and a form called EditNote and an event handler called mnuFormatUpper_Click `UEd!EditNote::mnuFormatUpper_Click`

Comment: enable the communication TCP/IP ports in the firewall configuration on System C? What is different in the code and its setup used on System B (works) and System C (only VB works)?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the registry on system C contained several entries on how to connect to the instrument, and in one, there was a slightly wrong IP address. I do not know why this key was used by my 32bit FP software and another one by the 32bit VB6 test application, but changing the IP address was one factor.

The other factor was to run the software in compatibility mode for Windows 7 on Windows 7 SP1. I don't know why that is necessary  (because it works without compatibility mode on Windows SP1 on system B), but I would like to get rid of it asap ...